# Elasticsearch: combine function scores

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I'm scoring es query with three `functions`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "score_mode": "multiply",
  "boost_mode": "replace",
  "functions": [
    { f1 },
    { f2 },
    { f3 }
  ]
}
```

so the score would be: `f1(doc) * f2(doc) * f3(doc)`.

But what I want is `f1(doc) * f2(doc) + f3(doc)`, any solutions?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: @JamesDrinkard ES 5.1

Answer (score 2):

This might work, i.e. we multiply the scores of functions f1 and f2 together and then we add that score to the query score which is another `function_score` query just for f3.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { "match_all": {}},
          "functions": [
            {
              "f3": {...}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "f1": {...}
        },
        {
          "f2": {...}
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a **sum** option for the score mode

`"score_mode": "sum",`

this should allow you to sum the scores.

see f.e. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: I know that, but it would give me: `f1(doc) + f2(doc) + f3(doc)`, instead of `f1(doc) * f2(doc) + f3(doc)`