# function_score with nested score_modes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a `function_score` query that looks like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                "script_score": { // f0
                        "script": {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field_value_factor": { // f1
                        ...
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field_value_factor": { // f2
                        ...
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field_value_factor": { // f3
                        ...
                    }
                },
            ],
            "score_mode": "multiply",
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

Current query calculates the scores as `_score * (f0 * f1 * f2 * f3)` but I want the final score to be `_score * (f0 + (f1 * f2 * f3))`.

I don't know if it is possible to have like a single function_score query with `sum` and `multiply` score modes?

I am using `ElasticSearch-6.2`.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110450/elasticsearch-combine-function-scores/49556069#49556069

Comment: @Val Thanks for the response. I'll try that out. Do I just need to replace `"query": { "match_all": {}}` with my `multi_match` query?

Comment: That thread only shows how to correctly line up functions in order to achieve the equation your expect, it probably doesn't fit your use case 100%, though. But yes, in any case, you need to use your `multi_match` query instead of the dummy `match_all` one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch: combine function scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110450/elasticsearch-combine-function-scores)